# Loss of tables after executing Oracle IMPDP "Empty_file.dmp" with empty file

Tags: oracle11g, impdp

After executing the command IMPDP Empty_File.dmp I lost all tables.

Is there a way to restore the schema?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I was mistaken. No issue with teh IMPDP command, there was a drop meanwhile in the script.